# Refresh Token Google Auth in Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-apps-script, google-oauth

I have a code in ruby that calls to a google apps script that create a spreadsheet report. But this generation will take more than 20 minutes( a lot of info) but after a couple of minutes I receive the message Error calling API! execution expired.

I am using the following code:

```
  OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
  APPLICATION_NAME = 'GoogleService'
  SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
  CERT_PATH = Gem.loaded_specs['google-api-client'].full_gem_path+'/lib/cacerts.pem'
  ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = CERT_PATH

  def self.authorize
    dir_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
    client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file("#{dir_path}/client_secret.json")
    token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: "#{dir_path}/google_service.yaml")
    authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(
        client_id, SCOPE, token_store)
    user_id = 'default'
    credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
    if credentials.nil?
      url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(
          base_url: OOB_URI)
      p "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " +
            "resulting code after authorization"
      p url
      code = gets
      credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
          user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
    end
    credentials
  end

  def self.create_spreadsheet(environment, root_path)

    id_spreadsheet = nil

    scrip_id = 'MerlVgs0vXonNfecv1XNrXTOzpl-Lo'

    # Initialize the API
    service = Google::Apis::ScriptV1::ScriptService.new
    service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
    service.authorization = self.authorize

    # Create an execution request object.
    request = Google::Apis::ScriptV1::ExecutionRequest.new
    request.function = 'createSpreadsheet'
    request.parameters = [environment, timestamp]

    begin
      # Make the API request.
      resp = service.run_script(scrip_id, request)

      if resp.error
        # The API executed, but the script returned an error.

        # Extract the first (and only) set of error details. The values of this
        # object are the script's 'errorMessage' and 'errorType', and an array of
        # stack trace elements.
        error = resp.error.details[0]

        puts "Script error message: #{error['errorMessage']}"

        if error['scriptStackTraceElements']
          # There may not be a stacktrace if the script didn't start executing.
          puts "Script error stacktrace:"
          error['scriptStackTraceElements'].each do |trace|
            puts "\t#{trace['function']}: #{trace['lineNumber']}"
          end
        end
      else
        id_spreadsheet = resp.response['result']
      end

    rescue Exception => e
      # The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
      puts "Error calling API!"
      puts e.message
    end

    id_spreadsheet
  end
```

How should I modify my code in order that the token don't expire?

I will appreciate any guide to do this thanks

Regards,
Walter

Comment: sorry this is not related but can you tell me how you created `google_service.yaml` ?